# Jackson databinding issue with Maven

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, maven-2, lombok

I'm facing an issue where I have a maven project with Java POJOs.

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;

/**
 * User DTO.
 */
@Builder
@Getter
public class UserDto {
  private String username;

}
```

I'm have added this maven dependency to another Spring boot based project.
I'm getting the following exception during the application tests.

org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: Type definition error:
 nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of com.models.UserDto (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)

However, whenever I add the spring boot starter parent dependency to the maven project I see no errors and the application works as expected.

Note: Also, the project works by adding a default constructor to the pojo. But my question is why would it work with the Spring boot starter added?

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Comment: Without a default constructor, I don't see how this works in any scenario. Please post a minimal example of your Spring Boot app where you're claiming this works.

Comment: Which versions of Lombok are used with and without the spring parent? I suspect this is due to a changed Lombok version that is managed by the spring parent.